# Android 8: Attempt to read from field 'android.content.Intent com.android.server.am.TaskRecord.intent' on a null object reference;

Tags: android

Android 8. Start my app and immediate minimize. After few seconds I get error:

```
startActivity called from finishing ActivityRecord{7497c34 u0 com.myproject..dev/com.myproject.activity.SplashActivity t-1 f}; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=com.myproject..dev/com.myproject.activity.RegistrationActivity }
Exception during pending activity launch pal=com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor$PendingActivityLaunch@a454565
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.content.Intent com.android.server.am.TaskRecord.intent' on a null object reference
 at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.computeSourceStack(ActivityStarter.java:1425)
 at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityUnchecked(ActivityStarter.java:983)
 at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:953)
 at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.doPendingActivityLaunchesLocked(ActivityStarter.java:1964)
 at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$MainHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:2055)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
 at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

This error has only on Android 8. In another Android version has no this error.

In stacktrace no reference to specific row (as you can see). Only name of activity (**SplashActivity**).

Here my **SplashActivity**:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, RegistrationActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: add your code where it crashes

Comment: In stacktrace no reference to specific row (as you can see). Only name of activity. Here my SplashActivity: public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, RegistrationActivity.class));
    }
}

Comment: It's happening for me too

Comment: @Alex Did you find more information about the crash? I got the same stacktrace from my app recently, but on a device running 5.1.1

Comment: Same here! If it's fixed by somebody, please let me know

Comment: For me the issue was a `BroadcastReceiver` that called `finishActivity()` but was not properly unregistered during activity shutdown. I also only experienced the issue in Android 5.1.1.